# Connection Timeout Glassfish Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, session-timeout

Some of my customers get a connection timeout when they are requesting my Java EE application:

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Exceptions.makeIOException(Exceptions.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:958)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:682)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:343)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:132)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:951)
    ... 36 more
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:48.976+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [jsf.application.resource.unable_to_serve_from_library] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1416301788976] [levelValue: 900] [[
  JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:48.977+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1416301788977] [levelValue: 900] [[

java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOTransport.java:1252)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeComposite0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:48.979+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1416301788979] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Exceptions.makeIOException(Exceptions.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:958)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:186)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(Channels.java:469)
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:358)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:132)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:951)
    ... 36 more
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:48.983+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1416301788983] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: Connection closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.TaskQueue.onClose(TaskQueue.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.onClose(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:613)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.closeConnection(TCPNIOTransport.java:611)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$2.run(NIOConnection.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler$RunnableTask.run(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTaskQueue(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTasks(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.preSelect(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:48.986+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1416301788986] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: Connection closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.TaskQueue.onClose(TaskQueue.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.onClose(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:613)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.closeConnection(TCPNIOTransport.java:611)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$2.run(NIOConnection.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler$RunnableTask.run(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTaskQueue(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTasks(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.preSelect(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:48.988+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1416301788988] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: Connection closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.TaskQueue.onClose(TaskQueue.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.onClose(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:613)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.closeConnection(TCPNIOTransport.java:611)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$2.run(NIOConnection.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler$RunnableTask.run(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTaskQueue(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTasks(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.preSelect(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:49.001+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [jsf.application.resource.unable_to_serve_from_library] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1416301789001] [levelValue: 900] [[
  JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:49.002+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1416301789002] [levelValue: 900] [[

java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOTransport.java:1252)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeComposite0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:49.016+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1416301789016] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOTransport.java:1252)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeComposite0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:49.020+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [jsf.application.resource.unable_to_serve_from_library] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1416301789020] [levelValue: 900] [[
  JSF1064: Ressource 72dpi_4c_HL_WBM_de.jpg aus Bibliothek images kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:49.020+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1416301789020] [levelValue: 900] [[

java.io.IOException: Connection closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.TaskQueue.onClose(TaskQueue.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.onClose(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:613)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.closeConnection(TCPNIOTransport.java:611)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$2.run(NIOConnection.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler$RunnableTask.run(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTaskQueue(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTasks(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.preSelect(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:49.026+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1416301789026] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: Connection closed
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.TaskQueue.onClose(TaskQueue.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.onClose(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:613)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.closeConnection(TCPNIOTransport.java:611)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$2.run(NIOConnection.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler$RunnableTask.run(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTaskQueue(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTasks(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.preSelect(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:329)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:48.978+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1416301788978] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOTransport.java:1252)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeComposite0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:49.049+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [jsf.application.resource.unable_to_serve_from_library] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1416301789049] [levelValue: 900] [[
  JSF1064: Ressource logo.jpg aus Bibliothek images kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:49.053+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1416301789053] [levelValue: 900] [[

java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOTransport.java:1252)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeComposite0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2014-11-18T10:09:49.054+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1416301789054] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOTransport.java:1252)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.writeComposite0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

The application is a full stack Java EE Application running on a GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89)
Browsers: IE 9 and Firefox (version not know)

Comment: I've seen this on Chrome 36, 37, and 38 as well. Exact same full stack (the first stack error anyway `java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`). observed on Java 8 build 5 and build 25. However, no issues with the same webapp using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and Java 6 build 35.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: @ArtyMcFly he uses JSF and primefaces component library. Indeed, GlassFish build 89 has this problem, I encountered it too before moving to GlassFish 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing you literally had the EXACT same issue I've been having, I decided to start digging. It appears that this is specifically a [glassfish 4.0 bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20681) fixed in [version 4.1 (download link)](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html). I decided to install and use 4.1. I noticed improvements to my issues almost immediately! After several minutes of testing I did not observe the `java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` that I typically saw.

Alternatively, if you are feeling adventurous it appears some developers found other possible fixes (from comments in the ticket manager):

> I've since increased all timeouts in glassfish, updated my JDK, and reduced the size of my WAR and I no longer see this exception. I don't know which step killed the exception but it's definitely gone.

At that being said, as for a better explanation of what exactly is causing this issue; one of Neatbean's dev's stated:

> First some background, which should offer some insight as to why there is a change in behavior between GF 3.x and 4.
>
> GF 4 uses Grizzly 2.3, which, for all intents and purposes, was a re-write of Grizzly 1.9 (used in GF 3.x). Grizzly 2.3 is much more sensitive to memory use than 1.9, and in this case, it has kind of bitten us.
>
> There are two issues in play that are causing the problem. First is the small socket write buffer size. The default write buffer size on RH and Ubuntu is 16K. In Grizzly, in order to conserve memory, will only allow 4x the write buffer size to be queued before we block the writer. In the case of the attached test case, there are several artifacts that are over 200K. When these are written, the initial writes made by the default Servlet will exceed the max queued data size and cause the writer to block. Because all worker threads are blocked, the async write queue is no longer being drained and the page, as far as the user is concerned, hangs when loading. Here's where the second issue comes in. By default, there are only five worker threads. In the case of the test case, there are at least five requests coming in that are requesting large resources. Due to this, all of the worker threads are blocked and all I/O comes to a halt.
>
> As was observed, increasing the write buffer size that GF uses, helps alleviate the issue, but at the cost of memory per connection. One could also increase the number of threads, but there's no guarantee that all of those threads wouldn't eventually be blocked when up scaling the number of clients.
>
> So, the proper fix will be to make sure that when we do block, that all async queue I/O is performed in the selector vs the worker thread. However, we need to be careful of which thread we use to perform the notification to unblock the thread and continue writing. Additionally, we should probably consider re-writing the default servlet to leverage the non-blocking api added in 3.1 [1]. (NOTE: these details are more for me). Will be working on this fix today. Hopefully, I'll have something to test later today or tomorrow.
>
> [1] https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20872

Comment: Side note, if anyone does their development in Netbeans and relies on it to do your server stuff, you cannot install GF4.1 on anything before Netbeans 8.0.1, Netbeans will tell you that that GF4.1 is not valid -- it does however come packaged with Netbeans 8.0.1.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest two solutions over here, depending on the situation you should choose.
The first and permanent solution is to optimize the query which is taking a longer time than the glassfish settings for the connection timeout.
Second, as a temporary solution, increase the connection timeout based on the query taking time to complete.